# Where are there areas in a program full of jmp instructions?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, reverse-engineering, api-hook

I am learning about debugging programs and stumpled upon an area I don't understand. Why is this area, as seen in the picture below, full of jump instructions to different addresses?

[image]

I'm learning about hooks and wanted to see my hooking function (`hookingFunction`) through x32dbg. It has the prototype of `LoadLibraryA` as that's the function I want to hook.

[image]

Here is the `LoadLibrary` prototype:

```
typedef HMODULE(__stdcall* LoadLibraryType) (LPCSTR filename);

static LoadLibraryType loadlib;

HMODULE __stdcall hookingFunction(LPCSTR filename) {

    std::cout << "hello from hookingFunction" << std::endl;

    return loadlib(filename);
}
```

When printing the base address of the `hookingFunction` I get the following address:

```
std::cout << std::hex << "hookingFunction, base address: " << hookingFunction << std::endl; 
// Output: "hookingFunction, base address: 7C061410"
```

Following the address in x32dbg I land here:

[image]

When following "jmp 713B" relative to 7C061410, I land at the actual function I wanted to land at in the first place

[image]

But why do we first need to visit the address 7C061410? And why is this area full of jmp instructions?

I hope it makes sense, and thank you for reading.

Comment: It could be anywhere in your code.  Most likely, it is a *jump table*.  Jump tables can be in `switch/case` statements, virtual tables, menu processing, message table, etc.  Search the internet for "jump table".

Comment: Could be incremental linking.

Comment: Jump table or incremental linking, thanks I'll read up on that!

Comment: Another topic worth learning about - IAT, Imports Address Table.

Comment: Thanks, @arrowd. I'll read up on that. Another thing, reading about jump tables and incremental linking it seemed more like a jump table to me. What info do you need to verify that?